# Particular ServiceControl update from 4.0.1 to 4.1.0 issues, audit does not update

Tags: nservicebus, nsb-servicecontrol

I just updated Particular ServiceControl from 4.0.1 to 4.1.0.  The ServiceControl instance updated, but the ServiceControl.Audit intance will not update. Clicking on the update link does not do anything.

Outside of  completely uninstalling the software then reinstalling it, is there a way to get the created ServiceControl.Audit instance to update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed with version 4.3.1.  Upgraded with no issues from 4.1.0 to 4.3.1.